# Preference setIcon to ColorDrawable does not work on Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: android, android-preferences

In my app I use the following line to distinguish some preferences:

```
preference.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(color));
```

In Android versions prior to Lollipop it works fine and the preference shows a square icon of the selected color, but in Lollipop none is shown.

Any idea for how to solve it?

Thanks

Here is a solution that is working for me:

```
preference.setIcon(getPreferenceIcon(color));

function Drawable getPreferenceIcon(int color)
{
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) return new ColorDrawable(color);
  int bitmap_size = 64;
  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap_size, bitmap_size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(color);
  canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, bitmap_size, bitmap_size), paint);
  return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Yes, definitely does not work in Lollipop. I edit my question to include the code that works in Lollipop

Comment: @TheMatrix You should answer your own question and not just leave it as a comment since it is working

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of The Matrix's answer, I removed the check on the version since it was also not working properly on Ice Cream Sandwich (a thin line was displayed, not a square):

```
private Drawable getPreferenceIcon(int color) {
    int size = 200;// Set to a big size to fit all screens, will be contained anyway in the preference row
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.eraseColor(color);

    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to do it in the XML file, here's an easy solution:

```
<Preference
    ...
    android:icon="@color/colorSome"/>
```

It's a simple solution if you don't want to change the icon in-code.