# Why does ColorDrawable(color) not working properly in Android lollipop and above

Tags: android, drawable

I've faced with such issue: 
In Android below Lollipop I can use this construction:

```
.setDrawable(new ColorDrawable(COLOR));
```

But this has no effect in Android above Lollipop, only creating `BitmapDrawable` with colored canvas gives the same result. 
What is the problem?

Comment: which class are you using setDrawable() on? It's not on View or ImageView.

Comment: i think you need to parse the color example -- Color.parseColor("#99000000")  -- but im not sure

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it doesn't work with lollipop - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401278/preference-seticon-to-colordrawable-dont-works-with-android-5-0) there is an example over there for how to use it in lollipop, as you said, `BitmapDrawable`:

```
preference.setIcon(getPreferenceIcon(color));

function Drawable getPreferenceIcon(int color)
{
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) return new ColorDrawable(color);
  int bitmap_size = 64;
  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap_size, bitmap_size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(color);
  canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, bitmap_size, bitmap_size), paint);
  return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
}
```